# Scale Image in HTML Header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, image-scaling

I want to scale the below image to the height of the header. Can anyone please tell me why it is not working?

```css
html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #header {
      background-color: green;
      height: 10%;
    }
    
    #body {
      background-color: blue;
      height: 70%;
    }
    
    #footer {
      background-color: orange;
      height: 20%;
    }
    
    img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .scaleableImage {
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
    }
    
    .scaleableImage img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    
  </style>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <a href="#" class="scaleableImage">
          <img src="https://www.googlewatchblog.de/wp-content/uploads/google-logo-perfekt.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <span>Second</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <span>Third</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="body">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <span>First</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <span>Second</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/27qmjpzx/

Comment: Because `.row` in Bootstrap does not define a height, it overflows out of the 10% high header.

Comment: Hey Mty, it's better to include your code in the question itself. This will help anyone to quickly see what you have tried so far. Additionally, they can copy the code to their answer by clicking the button, adjust it and post it. This will help to get an answer quickly. Here's how you can do it yourself the next time. [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets)

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted your CSS with the main changes being the following.

```
#header .row {
  max-height: 100%;
}

#header .col-2 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

This limits the `row` class within the header to a max height of 100%. As you set `#header` to 10%, `row` will stay within that height. Also, padding set on `col-2` was preventing the image from using the full space. Add padding back as you see fit, but keep in mind that it will shrink the image accordingly if the `col` class width is reduced. Below is a working example.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#header {
  background-color: green;
  height: 10%;
}

#body {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 70%;
}

#footer {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20%;
}

#header .row {
  max-height: 100%;
}

#header .col-2 {
  padding: 0;
}

.scaleableImage img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <a href="#" class="scaleableImage">
          <img src="https://www.googlewatchblog.de/wp-content/uploads/google-logo-perfekt.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <span>Second</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <span>Third</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="body">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <span>First</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <span>Second</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```